# Is there any way that I can alter this SQL query so that it doesn't return any results containing whitespace?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query that I use for a search function (shown below)

```
SELECT t.op_id, t.op_desc FROM operator
WHERE UPPER(t.op_id) LIKE UPPER(?);
```

when my web page first loads, it simply returns every operator in the table.

There a few entries in the database for which the operator id (t.op_id) contains some white space "Operator A". Is there any way that I can alter this query so that results that contain white space in the operator name are excluded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ignore white spaces, you can try

```
WHERE NOT LIKE '% %'
```

This will [perform the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451608/which-is-faster-instr-or-like) as `INSTR`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
SELECT t.op_id, t.op_desc FROM operator
WHERE t_op_id not like '% %'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `trim` function.  I'm assuming your operator name column is `op_name`.  Please try the following:

```
SELECT t.op_id, t.op_desc FROM operator
WHERE UPPER(t.op_id) LIKE UPPER(?) and instr(trim(t.op_name), ' ') <= 0;
```

Comment: @Randy, yes thanks for correcting.  I've updated my answer to use `instr` as you pointed out in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you might also try:

```
where INSTR(t_op_id,' ') <= 0
```

Comment: You probably wanted the other way around: `where INSTR(t_op_id,' ') <= 0` - the OP wants to exclude ones with whitespaces.