# Searching for a faster query than like '%something.%'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big list of domain names, and a big list of words. I want to check how many domain names in my list have each of these words at the end of them. I tried 2 queries but both are taking too much time to execute. Trying to find out if there is any way to make the query faster.

First I tried this query, it is taking around 50 minutes to return results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM   table 
WHERE  domain_name LIKE '%my_word.%';
```

Then I thought maybe if I remove the `.%` from it, maybe it would go faster so I tried this, but it is still slow:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM   table 
WHERE  SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.', 1) LIKE '%my_word';
```

Anyone has an idea of a query that might go faster?

Thanks.

Comment: what mysql table engine you are using ??

Comment: I am using innodb engine

Comment: Can you provide some sample matches?

Comment: what do you mean by sample matches? for example the word `best` exists at the beginning OR at the end of 383,956 domain names. That's what I am searching for the query to find if the word is at the beginning of the domain is very fast, but the one to find if it is at the end is VERY slow

Comment: Even I have the same problem right now..!!!

Comment: iv read INSTR is faster than like

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille [here is a test](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2451665/2094094)

Comment: this means thy are the same performance wise ?

Answer (score 0):

You need double `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `SUBSTRING` from the end for a word match.
The following would count *example.com* as well as the *example.de* and *somethingexample.com*

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t1
 WHERE SUBSTRING(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.', -2),
          '.',1), length('example')*(-1)) = 'example';
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f250e/4)

Also, you can avoid typing pattern 2 times, using variables ([**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f250e/9)):

```
SET @WORD = 'example';
SET @LNGTH = length(@WORD)*(-1);
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t1
 WHERE SUBSTRING(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.', -2),
          '.',1), @LNGTH) = @WORD;
```

Comment: I don't want subdomains I want domains, codeexample.com should count if I am searching for the word `example`

Comment: yes, but to find the count of domains that have `example` at the beggining like `examplecode.com` is very fast, like it takes few seconds, the issue is the end of the word

Comment: this won't work, for sure. and you're still missing a `,` between '.' and the 1. thanks for the help.

Comment: trying it, will let you know

Comment: down to 27 mins at the place of 50 using this: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table  WHERE RIGHT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.',1), length('men')) = 'men';

Comment: no, ran another took 50 min again, I think it is the same thing :(

Comment: @CodeBird how is that even possible, lol? Probably, counting length 1 time will save some resources. I updated second query (with variables), can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

For best results, you need to create FULLTEXT index on your data, use innoDb mysql engine

eg

```
SELECT  *
FROM    domain_name
WHERE   MATCH(data) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2 +word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: will this work with no spaces? And even if it does, then it would get me back results where the word is in the middle of the domain like if I am search for `example` it would get me `codeexampletest.com` as result, which I don't want. Thanks for trying

Comment: #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes :(

Comment: innoDb mysql engine supports , but you are using is myIsam

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by fulltext index but it is compatible only in version 5.6 for innodb and you can use in any version for myisam tables.

Create Full Text Index by below command-

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD FULLTEXT(domain_name);
```

Now you can use query as per below-

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE MATCH (domain_name) AGAINST ('your_word');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your query is not looking for separate words, I believe it would't benefit from a full text index (the engine won't know how to parse the domain into individual words). I also don't believe `substring` solutions will yield better performance than the `LIKE` operator. You are dealing with simple string matching and databases are not the best place to run it.

That said, I believe the best you can do to improve the speed for this query is to reduce the number of bytes that need to be read from disk. You can achieve it by creating a simple index on this column (the query will still be an index scan, but it will be cheaper than the table scan). Another thing you can do is to remove unnecessary characters from this column, like `.com` or `.net`, since it will allow for more *meaningful data* to be fetched in every access to disk.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I can't remove the .com and .net etc... the database is for a running website that is actually a whois website, whoisology.com, so can't really remove info

Comment: Hi, @CodeBird, I am sorry, I wasn't clear, I didn't mean to remove the `.com` or `.net` from the existing column, but to create a new column, optimized for this purpose, without the bytes that don't matter.