# SQL SELECT from table when substring is in a string

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a table named `table1` in a sqlite3 database (via python) with two columns named 'id' and 'string' and here are the three entries in the table:

```
   id                string
  'a'               'google'
  'b'               'apple'
  'c'            'application'
```

so let's say I want all the rows with 'app' in them, so how would i do that? I'm looking for something like this:

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 'app' in string`

which would in theory return the last 2 rows....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE string LIKE '%app%'
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/68bdc/1)**

**UPDATE:**

When you use a front wildcard (`LIKE '%app%'`), the performance will be roughly the same.

If you want string starting with `app`, then using `LIKE 'app%'` would be better. Here's the reason :-

> The part before the first wildcard serves as an access predicate, that is, they limit the scanned index range. The
>   remaining characters do not narrow the scanned index
>   range—non-matching entries are just left out of the result.

Comment: but i've heard that like is slow.. how can i make it fast?

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi - Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451608/which-is-faster-instr-or-like

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi Does all the value in field starts with 'app' or it can be anywhere in the string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE string LIKE '%app%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You need to use the LIKE '%' operator in SQL. It's for string matching.

Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE string LIKE '%app%'
```

Since you didn't mention whether 'app' should be positioned at the beginning of string or the end, I've wrapped the string 'app' around two '%', so that it will locate the 'app' string anywhere inside string.