# MySQL Subquery From the Same Table

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table with many rows and I'd like to speed up my query. This is the original query:

```
cursor.execute("""select id, data
                        from events
                        where processed IS NULL and instr(data, 'Captain') = 0;""")
```

I thought I could speed things up by first selecting only the unprocessed rows and then searching the text of the `data` variable. But this is also slow.

```
    cursor.execute("""select x.id, x.data
                    from
                    (select a.id, a.data from events as a where a.processed IS NULL) as x
                    where instr(x.data, 'Captain') = 0;""")
```

Any thoughts on how I could filter the processed column for NULL before searching through `data`?

Comment: Another route you could use is to add an index to the data column, and switch `instr` to `like`. That would make filtering on the data column faster. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451608/which-is-faster-instr-or-like/22171511

Comment: *But this is also slow* Moreover, is is slower than initial variant - simply you cannot detect this difference.

Comment: @juergend OP needs in rows where `'Captain'` substring is NOT present.

Comment: If the table contains many columns then the index by `(processed, data, id)` will help. If the percent of the rows with `processed IS NULL` is low (5% or less) then the index by `(processed)` will help (but it is possible that you'd force its usage). In another cases I do not see the way to improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `instr(data, 'Captain')` could be changed to `data NOT LIKE '%Captain%'`?  Either formulation has to read every row, so I doubt if there would be a speed difference.

Also consider `FULLTEXT(data)` and `NOT MATCH(data) AGAINST('+Captain' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.  `FULLTEXT` may not help because of the `NOT`.

As for your thought on a subquery, I think it won't help.  After all that is essentially what is going on.

What *might* matter is the indexes you have and the cardinality of them.  If `processed` is *rarely* `NULL` (say, less than 10% of the rows), then `INDEX(processed)` will speed things up.