# mysql where a column does not contain regular expression with value from another column

Tags: mysql

I have the below table and I need to find all rows where the `resource_path` does not contain the `code` in the string.

```
id | code | resource_path
1   abc01    /this/is/path/to/resource/abc01/xyz.jpg
2   abc02    /this/is/path/to/resource/abc02/xyz.png
3   abc02    /this/is/path/to/resource/xyz.png
```

I have tried the following query

```
SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE resource NOT IN (select code from aTable) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

but this returns everything.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try something like this `resource NOT LIKE CONCAT('%/', code, '/%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM aTable where resource_path not like concat('%', code, '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

@Agnelo Dsouza answer is great. I put it in a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i5EBADE9ZZyTAsTXV27aDu/0) and added another option, as it might give you a better [performence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171511/1157173):

```
SELECT * FROM aTable where INSTR(resource_path,code) = 0;
```