# Which is faster INSTR vs Like Prefix For varchar In MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If my goal is to find out if there is a string in the column. The column has no unique btree index. Which is faster and more efficient: INSTR vs LIKE prefix for varchar in MYSQL, and why?

Or are there other more-efficient methods?

```
INSTR(column, 'value') > 0
```

vs

```
column LIKE 'value%'
```

I looked up several questions, but there were only questions and answers about wild cards front and back.

For example,

```
column LIKE '%value%'
```

Comment: @GSerg That won't help him, because it's using a leading wildcard and the question specifically asked about matches without the leading wildcard.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The duplicate [covers that too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2451691/11683). And the similar performance otherwise. And the advice to use fulltext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same.

`column like 'value%'` is a **starts with** match, equivalent to `INSTR(column, 'value') = 1`, rather than `INSTR(column, 'value') > 0`.

On the other hand, `INSTR(column, 'value') > 0` is a **contains anywhere** match, equivalent to `column LIKE '%value%'` instead of `column LIKE 'value%'`.

Of these four expressions, `column LIKE 'value%'` is likely to perform the best, because it's the only one that still has a chance of using any index for the column.

But it sounds like you want the *contains anywhere* match, and there's probably not any meaningful difference between `column like '%value%'` and `INSTR(column, 'value') > 0`. The best option here is likely a [full-text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

A simple test on my test table (`integers`) shows that LIKE is faster.

```sql
MySQL [test]> select * from integers where instr(t2,'A')>0;
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
| i  | t1                                   | f        | t2   |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
| 42 | 8f0c8b96-aa60-11eb-aa31-309c23b7280c | 0.983418 | ABC  |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
1 row in set (24.08 sec)

MySQL [test]> select * from integers where instr(t2,'A')>0;
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
| i  | t1                                   | f        | t2   |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
| 42 | 8f0c8b96-aa60-11eb-aa31-309c23b7280c | 0.983418 | ABC  |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
1 row in set (24.11 sec)

MySQL [test]> explain select * from integers where instr(t2,'A')>0;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | integers | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2104867 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MySQL [test]> select * from integers where t2 like 'A%';
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
| i  | t1                                   | f        | t2   |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
| 42 | 8f0c8b96-aa60-11eb-aa31-309c23b7280c | 0.983418 | ABC  |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
1 row in set (1.00 sec)

MySQL [test]> select * from integers where t2 like 'A%';
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
| i  | t1                                   | f        | t2   |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
| 42 | 8f0c8b96-aa60-11eb-aa31-309c23b7280c | 0.983418 | ABC  |
+----+--------------------------------------+----------+------+
1 row in set (1.00 sec)

MySQL [test]> explain select * from integers where t2 like 'A%';
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | integers | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2104867 |    11.11 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

This table has 2621442 records, in MySQL 8.0.29, with this DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `integers` (
  `i` int NOT NULL,
  `t1` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `t2` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`i`),
  KEY `integers_t1` (`t1`),
  KEY `idx_f` (`f`),
  KEY `even` (((`i` % 2)))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci STATS_AUTO_RECALC=1
```